# Printing out Dictionary Keys in a More Attractive Way

Tags: python, dictionary, text

Good Evening,

It's not too difficult to print out a dictionary's keys:

```
print(dict_example.keys())
```

But this method spits out a rather unattractive presentation:

```
dict_keys(['A', 'B', 'C'])
```

Is there a way to get Python to spit out the keys to a dictionary in a more attractive way.  For instance, like this:

```
A, B, C
```

Comment: Few more options to pretty print the whole dictionary https://www.delftstack.com/howto/python/python-pretty-print-dictionary/#:~:text=pprint%20is%20a%20Python%20module,the%20given%20string%20or%20object.

Comment: `print(*dict_example,sep=", ")` should give you the output you are looking for (you don't need to use the `.keys()` method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be using a `*` in `print` like:

```
print(*dict_example.keys()) #A B C
```

adding a separator would make it more readable:

```
print(*dict_example.keys(),sep=', ') #A, B, C
```

If you want a more detailed one:

```
print("\n".join("{}\t{}".format(k, v) for k, v in dict_example.items())) 
#A     dict_example['A']
#B     dict_example['B']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the string method `join` for this:

```
dict_example = {
    'A': 1, 
    'B': 2, 
    'C': 3,
}
print(', '.join(dict_example))

# output:
# A, B, C
```

Since `str.join` expects an iterable of some sort, passing in a dictionary as its argument means that it will join all of its keys into a single string (since iterating over a dictionary means iterating over its keys).

You'll need to modify it slightly if one or more keys aren't strings, by explicitly casting them to string prior to joining. In this case, we can pass in the generator expression `str(k) for k in dict` to `str.join` in order to do just that:

```
dict_example = {
    'A': 1, 
    'B': 2, 
    'C': 3, 
    10.5: 'xxx',
}
print(', '.join(str(k) for k in dict_example))

# output:
# A, B, C, 10.5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) method:

```
>>> print(", ".join(d.keys()))
a, b, c
```